# How to continuously ping and result changes an image

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops, ping

Hoping you can help me out here.

I am having a issue figuring out how to loop a piece of ping code and result ( if true or false ) changes an image.

here is my code running on a button click,

My aim here is to basically automise the app so the user does not have to click the refresh icon,

I have read a bit and am thinking I could use a while loop, But am unsure on how to use sleep with it.

The other method would be to use a thread with sleep?

I have also asked on MSDN to get the most feedback possible.

```
    //Declaration of Global Variables (IP's)
    public static string IP1, IP2, IP3;

    //Method Setting Variables(IP's)
    public static void setIP()
    {

        IP1 = Properties.Settings.Default.settingIP1;
        IP2 = Properties.Settings.Default.settingIP2;
        IP3 = Properties.Settings.Default.settingIP3;
    }

    //Method running Ping command
    public static bool PingTest(string toPing)
    {
    string host = toPing;
    bool result = false;
    Ping p = new Ping();

    try
    {
        PingReply reply = p.Send(host, 3000);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            return true;
    }
    catch { }
    return result;
    }

    //Refreshes IP1 then changes label to result
    private void btnRefreshIP1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        setIP();
        bool isConnected = false;
        isConnected = PingTest(IP1);

        if(isConnected == true)
        {
            lblsIP1.Foreground = Brushes.White;
            lblsIP1.Content = "Online";
        }
        else
        {
            lblsIP1.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            lblsIP1.Content = "Offline";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Timer! Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Use a DispatcherTimer to fire events at regular intervals.

Comment: Personally I would move this into a separate class, put the ping onto a timer, store the current status, and add a custom event for Lost, Gained, Succeeded, Failed, Changed etc. - then you can easily just attach your image change code to the event handler. Makes it nice and easy to use if you're monitoring a number of sites.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the replies! To answer Alexei, I what I mean by automise is that the user does not have to click the refresh buttons, the cope just loops on run, Yeah not sure my PC corrected the word

Comment: @Tolgahan Albayrak, I am not sure what you mean by timer or how to implement it, Can you elaborate please

Comment: @user3415389 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @RogerN and Octopoid, I am going to move the code into a class when I finish it up, I see timer mentioned here again, Can i store the current status in a variable? and just use a IF statement to change the image based on the variable string? I am monitoring 3 IP's and have not used event handlers before

Comment: @Tolgahan Albayarak, Thank you for the link I will be reading through it now.

Comment: As you say, you're monitoring 3 IPs - if you move this into it's own class FIRST, you can just create 3 instances of it, simplifying things. Classes are more than just a way of organizing your code.